# Selenium WebDriver - get options from hidden select

Tags: selenium, select, webdriver, hidden-field

I want to get all the options from a hidden select.
Select has "display: none;" part so I ran into a problem.

```
<select name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group" 
            class="" id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group" 
            onchange=" eurotax.change_type_group( this.value ); " 
            style="display: none; ">

        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="-1" class="special">2</option>
        <option value="16390">CD</option>
        <option value="17605">S</option>
        <option value="17636">SE</option>

</select>
```

My code:

```
Select tipSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group")));
for (WebElement b : tipSelect.getOptions()) {
            System.out.println(b.getText());
}
```

Please display code example if You have any.

firebug view:
http://imageshack.us/f/138/primjer.png/  LOOK THIS

Comment: I can't get option text. In this case "1", "2", "CD", "S", "SE".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to select elements in firebug with "display: none;" attribute. They will not be outlined on the page, but in the html tree structure.
[image: see example of verifying element with firebug with "display: none;" attribute]

Then, verify that you found element propertly with firebug

```
String optn=select[name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"] option[value="0"]
//optn1=select[name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"] option[value="-1"]
//optn2=select[name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"] option[value="16390"]
//optn3=select[name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"] option[value="17605"]
//optn4=select[name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"] option[value="17636"]
```

then try to use jscript executor (should always work not taking into consideration whether element visible or not)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+optn+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this work for you)

Answer (score 0):

The matter is selenium unable to click invisible elements (or interact with invisible elements in other ways). So js should help. I would resolve it in the following way:

```
String css1="ul>li:last-child>div[id=unos_select_wrap] select[id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"]>option[value='0']";
String css2="ul>li:last-child>div[id=unos_select_wrap] select[id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"]>option[value='-1']";
String css3="ul>li:last-child>div[id=unos_select_wrap] select[id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"]>option[value='16390']";
String css4="ul>li:last-child>div[id=unos_select_wrap] select[id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"]>option[value='17605']";
String css5="ul>li:last-child>div[id=unos_select_wrap] select[id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"]>option[value='17636']";

public void getOptionTextAndPrintIt(String cssSelector){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSelector+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();");
       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println(res);

}
public void allOptionValuesDepiction(){
getOptionTextAndPrintIt(css1);
getOptionTextAndPrintIt(css2);
getOptionTextAndPrintIt(css3);
getOptionTextAndPrintIt(css4);
getOptionTextAndPrintIt(css5);
}
```

Please let me know if something wrong as soon as you check.

Comment: It works! I've resolved a problem like this: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                String script = "var sb = [];"
                        + "var select = document.getElementById('_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group');"
                        + "for (var i=0; i<select.length; i++) {"
                        + "sb.push(select.options[i].text + ',');"
                        + "}"
                        + "return sb;";

Comment: Just using JavascriptExecutor and build a for loop for getting option text (select.options[i].text)